# If $x= 2$ find the value of $3^{x+2} + 5^x - 7^{x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, exponentiation

If $x= 2$ find the value of $3^{x+2} + 5^x - 7^{x-1}$

For this question do I simply replace $x$ as $2$ so the final answer would be $99$ or is there a more complicated procedure?

Comment: There is certainly a more complicated procedure thinkable - but hardly a simpler one. However, you should be careful to make the calculations *correctly*. I get $-14$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Not if what was meant was $3^{x+2} + 5^x - 7^{x-1}$. But either way the question asker hasn't taken proper care in posting the question.

Comment: @gina Even without proper typesetting in Latex (the math language used here) just simple brackets would go a long way to making your meaning clearer. Anyway, I've answered your question in the affirmative.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $3^{x+2} + 5^x - 7^{x-1}$ then yes the answer is $99$, and you get it by simple substitution as you did.